# Phone number error in struts2

Tags: java, string, struts2, integer

If i give a ten digits number like `1234567891` it works fine,

but why `9964289813` instead doesn't work ?

jsp:

```
<s:textfield key="personalDetailsDTO.mobile"    label="Mobile" />
```

dto:

```
private int mobile;
public int getMobile() {
    return mobile;
}

public void setMobile(int mobile) {
    this.mobile = mobile;
}
```

action:

```
public class RegisterAction extends ActionSupport{
    private PersonalDetailsDTO personalDetailsDTO;
    System.out.println(personalDetailsDTO.getMobile());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the max value of an integer is `2,147,483,647` (`2.147.483.647` in my country).

You are trying to insert `9,964,289,813`, that is higher.

That said, phone numbers can contain `+`, `(`, `)` and spaces...  don't use a numeric field for a phone number, just use a String.

Answer (score 1):

That does not fit into an `int`, as `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is `2^32 - 1`. Choose a different data type. Phone numbers shouldn't be numbers anyway, they can contain special characters, and start with zeroes.